# Is it possible to set include_path in my PHP application in Heroku?

Tags: php, heroku

As the title says... If so, how? Thanx for providing solutions such as links to official documentation related to it as well as just replying it is impossible! :)

Comment: Have you gone to heroku's support page and asked them?

Comment: It's so trivial, so I don't put it as an answer just a comment: Yes. And it works as usual. The docs are here: http://php.net/php.ini ans also http://php.net/set_include_path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Heroku documentation:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-php-settings#php-runtime-settings

It says you can add a file named `.user.ini` to your document root (not necessarily the same as your application root) with your custom php settings.

I hope this saves someone some time. I wasted a couple hours on this.

Quick note - your application root is `/app`, so in my case, I added `/app/includes` to the include_path

Answer (score 1):

Just to give a working example, and I'm guessing so you can access installed composer/pear packages or includes, I used the following setup:

.user.ini (in app root):

```
include_path=".:includes:vendor/composer"
```

Procfile (remote):

```
web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2
```

Procfile.test (local):

```
web: php -S 0.0.0.0:$PORT -c .user.ini
```